# Specifying a latent variable with a single indicator in lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I would like to run a SEM in `lavaan` with two multiple indicator variables and one single indicator variable. The single indicator is a person ability parameter from an IRT model.

My model looks somewhat like this:

```
model1 <- '
   Factor.A =~ a1 + a2 + a3 + a4
   Factor.B =~ b1 + b2 + b3 + b4
   Factor.C =~ c1
   c1~~c1(1-0.89)*c1
```

C1 is the single indicator. The reliability of the availity parameter is 0.89.

Question 1: Is the specification of the single indicator latent variable (Factor.C) correct?
And Question 2: How would one interprete the factor loading of the single indicator? In my model, I get 0.93 as the factor loading. Is it problematic that it is so high?

I looked in different forums, papers and other R support instruments but I couldnt find a satisfying answer to this issue. I wuould be very grateful if someone knows and likes to share how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Per these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example you should ask one question per post. Also, your second question, about interpreting results, is better suited to stats.stackexchange.com  Please consider taking the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

> Is the specification of the single indicator latent variable (Factor.C) correct?

No, you specify the righthand-side variable both before and after the operator.  Operators are only recognized when placed before the righthand-side variable (see `?model.syntax`)

```
c1 ~~ .11*c1
```

And unless your `c1` sample variance is exactly 1, then you can use labels to constrain the common- and unique-factor variances to the ratio of (un)reliability:

```
Factor.C =~ 1*c1
Factor.C ~~ commonVar*Factor.C
c1       ~~ uniqueVar*c1
## constraint consistent with commonVar/uniqueVar = .89 / .11
uniqueVar == commonVar * .11 / .89
```

> How would one interpret the factor loading of the single indicator?

With a single-indicator construct, it is more straight-forward to
think of it as a variance decomposition.  That is reflected by fixing the loading to 1 in my syntax above, so the variance of `c1` is simply the sum of common- and unique-factor variances.

When you fix `Factor.C`'s variance to 1 and estimate the loading, it is statistically equivalent, but the loading is the square-root of the common-factor variance component (i.e., the *SD*).